# Second monitor not showing

Tags: hardware, monitor, amd-ryzen

Hi I using amd ryzen 3 2200 
i using ubuntu 18.04
And I want use 2 monitor but only one monitor shown what should I do

#### EDIT

here my lspci | grep VGA

> 38:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega [Radeon Vega 8 Mobile] (rev c8)

and here my 
Thanks xrandr

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>   Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 720, current 1280 x 720, maximum 1280 x 720
>   default connected primary 1280x720+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>      1280x720      76.00*

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? What gives you: `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Right now, your question lacks any helpful description. The good thing is, you can simply edit your question and include as much description as you like. Please take the time to explain what you are doing where you hit a problem. Please read [about] and [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: sorry for that i did edit my qustion